# Run Tomcat on *:<port> instead of localhost:<port>

Tags: java, spring, virtual-machine, parallels

I am trying to access my localhost server from Parallels Desktop and facing some issues.

For example, I have an app on Spring Boot that runs on port 8081, and running `sudo lsof -PiTCP -sTCP:LISTEN` in Terminal gives me the following output:

`java      8168 username  107u  IPv6 0x53524f3d71f26ae5      0t0  TCP *:8081 (LISTEN)`

And the output for second application (not Spring Boot, but Spring inside Tomcat 7) is:

`java      7756 username  504u  IPv6 0x53524f3d6cfe6fa5      0t0  TCP localhost:8096 (LISTEN)`

I can easily access the first application from Parallels Desktop by address http://10.211.55.2:8081/, but doing the same for http://10.211.55.2:8096/ gives me this site can’t be reached error message.

So, how can I run my second application on *:8096 instead of localhost:8096?

Comment: Could not change address, but ngrok (https://ngrok.com/) helped me out

Comment: It's not _Spring_ you run on the port, but _Tomcat_.

Answer (score 1):

The IP address tomcat listens in is controlled by the [`address` attribute in the connector element](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html#Standard_Implementation) in tomcat configuration file server.xml.

To listen on all addresses, set the address to `0.0.0.0`:

```
<Connector port="8096" 
           address="0.0.0.0"
           ...other attributes.../>
```